# Google Analytics - tracking authenticated user page visits

Tags: google-analytics

I have Google Analytics running on our Community.  I am tracking page visits.  I would like to track authenticated user page visits.  Does anyone know of a way to determine which page visits are by authenticated users without adding code to each page that checks if the visitor is logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

If your page is visible to both authorised as well as public users there's no way to distinguish your audience without requiring additional effort. You could leverage [this existing post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214141/community-lightning-page-that-identifies-the-running-user) to figure out if a visitor is a guest user or not and [fire an event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:analyticsInteraction/documentation) to capture this within Google Analytics.